# How may number pairs $(n - 2, n)$ are there, less than $n$, where $(n – 2)$ is prime and $n$ is composite?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

I was wondering about number pairs, that differ by 2 on the natural numbers field. They can be twin primes, twin composites, and mixed.
The mixed can be 2 types, either the first is prime, the second is composite, or the first is composite, the second is prime.
I am specially interested in $\pi(n-2, n)$ , where $(n – 2)$ is prime and $n$ is composite.
Are there some upper limits in terms of the number of primes, or can we say something about them that has some connection with $\pi(n)$ ?

Comment: Your $n$ is doing double duty.  There are no $n$'s less than $n$.  Second, if $p$ is any odd prime, then $p+2$ is composite almost all the time.  So the number of pairs you're looking for is $\pi(n).$

Comment: So you say that $\pi(n-2, n)$ < $\pi(n)$, and the difference is the number of twin prime pairs up to n.

Answer (score 0):

all primes greater than 5 are 1,7,11,13,17,19,23, or 29 mod 30. Your $n-2$ prime $n$ composite cases are could be any of them mod 30  which means they have a maximum of ${4x\over 15}$ cases up to x, assuming all cases are possible at once ( they aren't) this is also a very weak upper bound for the number of primes.